# find value of k in joint probability distribution

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution, distributions

Question: The value of k that will make the function, f(x,y) = kxy for x=1,2,3 and y=1,2,3 a joint probability distribution is:
(a) 1/9
(b) 1/3
(c) 1/2
(d) 1/36
(e) none of these

This problem I found in an examination. I couldn't find any similar problems in stats books I have. I used multiple integration method using x and y two independent variables, got dissatisfied though.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Comment: You don't integrate, you sum; such problems are quite standard and are found in many, many books. [On this particular problem; by inspection the sum of xy over those values is obvious, since the double-sum of outer products of vectors simplifies trivially and the marginal sums on small problems over integers starting from 1 can be done in the head. Once I'd read the question, I had the answer in my head in well under a second ... before I'd even read the options at the bottom - usually such questions are made so the problem doesn't factorize so neatly.]

Answer (score 2):

Note that the total probability over all possible pairs $(x,y)$ must equal $1$. You need to find a $k$ that satisfies this condition.

Comment: I’m sorry. For what it’s worth, I deleted the solution and gave a more general hint.

Comment: +1 Thanks (I hadn't actually asked you to delete  -- presuming the OP had probably already seen it -- it was more for next time), but that's a good hint. (You can probably get away with something in between the two, though in this case it's probably suffficient.)